# How many connected components in this series?

Tags: python, probability

Consider a line of 25 adjacent colorless squares. Color in each individual square black with probability 3/4 or white with probability 1/4, independent of all other squares. A connected component is a maximal sequence of adjacent squares all with the same color. For example, BBWBWWWBBW has 6 connected components. Find the expected number of connected components in our line.

I calculate the result as 10. `(24 possibilities for changes) * 2*1/4*3*4 + 1 (since no changes means 1 connected component) = 10`. According to other sources the answer is indeed 10.

I tried to check this result in Python and got 13:

```
RUNS = 100000

sums = 0
for j in range(RUNS):
    x = []
    for i in range(25):
        x.append(randint(0,1))
    s = 1
    for i in range(1,25):
        if x[i] != x[i-1]:
            s += 1
    sums += s

print(sums/RUNS)
```

Obviously 10 is not 13. What is the correct answer and why is my reasoning/code wrong?

Or is there a high dependency on consecutive randint prompts?

Answer (score 0):

So, my previous answer was wrong (except in pointing out the real problem: you forgot the 0.75/0.25 probability in your simulation).

I keep the initial proof of dependency here for record, even if we, indeed, don't care of dependency.

But, well, since I've played with some code to check my hypothesis, let just to show it and show to write efficient simulation in python, nevertheless, here is mine (once corrected the bug that triggered a confirmation bias for my wrong reasoning)

```py
a=np.random.rand(100000,25)>=0.75 # False for black, True for white
1+(a[:,1:]!=a[:,:24]).sum(axis=1).mean()
```

`a[:,1:]!=a[:,:24]` is the list of changes (True for change). So `(a[:,1:]!=a[:,:24]).sum(axis=1)` is the number of changes per line. So just add `.mean()` to have the average number of changes, and +1 to add the initial component.

Another way to do a naive (and it is always better to be naive, to avoid to bring our bias in the simulation) yet exact computation (not relying on stochastic evaluation) is to compute a distribution of different scenarios.
Having P, a 2×26 array, such as `P[col,num]` is the probability to have that last element being of color col (0=black, 1=white) while the number of components being num.
Initialy, when only 1 element is known, we have `P[0,1]=0.75` and `P[1,1]=0.25`, and all the rest at 0.

And then

```py
def nextP(P):
   newP=np.zeros((2,26))
   newP[0,1:] = 0.75*(P[0,1:]+P[1,:25])
   newP[1,1:] = 0.25*(P[0,:25]+P[1,1:])
   return newP
```

So

```py
P=np.zeros((2,26))
P[0,1]=0.75
P[1,1]=0.25
nextP(P)
```

gives

```
array([[0.    , 0.5625, 0.1875, 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
        0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
        0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
        0.    , 0.    ],
       [0.    , 0.0625, 0.1875, 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
        0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
        0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    , 0.    ,
        0.    , 0.    ]])
```

meaning that with 2 elements, we have 56.25% chance to have 1 component the sequence ending with black, 6,25% chance to have 1 component ending with white, 18,75% chance to have 2 components ending with black, 18.75% chance to have 2 components ending with white.

```py
nextP(nextP(P))
```

is

```
array([[0.      , 0.421875, 0.1875  , 0.140625, 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      ],
       [0.      , 0.015625, 0.1875  , 0.046875, 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ,
        0.      , 0.      ]])
```

without checking everything, it makes sense. For example, we do have 4,6875% chance to have 3 components ending with white (0.25×0.75×0.25)

So,

```py
for i in range(24): P=nextP(P)
```

shows

```
array([[0.00000000e+00, 7.52543458e-04, 3.76271729e-04, 8.46611390e-03,
        3.95085316e-03, 3.96496335e-02, 1.70733297e-02, 1.00864340e-01,
        3.95320485e-02, 1.52822175e-01, 5.36275401e-02, 1.42623153e-01,
        4.39223762e-02, 8.22091246e-02, 2.16705266e-02, 2.86718055e-02,
        6.26308387e-03, 5.78515342e-03, 1.00135280e-03, 6.24104399e-04,
        7.99638593e-05, 3.13017941e-05, 2.63069374e-06, 5.49424794e-07,
        2.26566925e-08, 1.41604328e-09],
       [0.00000000e+00, 8.88178420e-16, 3.76271729e-04, 1.88135865e-04,
        3.95085316e-03, 1.83432468e-03, 1.70733297e-02, 7.26674776e-03,
        3.95320485e-02, 1.51890315e-02, 5.36275401e-02, 1.82594670e-02,
        4.39223762e-02, 1.29560238e-02, 2.16705266e-02, 5.38187924e-03,
        6.26308387e-03, 1.26081594e-03, 1.00135280e-03, 1.54725560e-04,
        7.99638593e-05, 8.68013554e-06, 2.63069374e-06, 1.68037136e-07,
        2.26566925e-08, 4.72014428e-10]])
```

So, for example, 5.49424794e-07 is the probability to have 23 components while ending with a black element.

Note that the fact that even number of components show an equal probability for case "ending with white" and "ending with black" has to do with what you say: we don't need independancy to linearly accumulate probability.

```py
P.sum(axis=0)
```

is the probability distribution of the number of components.

And

```py
(P*np.arange(26)).sum()
```

is the expected number of components
Which is exactly 10, indeed.
And this time, it is not an evaluation. It is an exact computation (with numerical error, of course, since there are some very small values in P. But still, not a monte carlo computation).
Yet, using naive consideration. For example this computation does take into account dependency tho we don't need it.

## Dependency proof

When element k is black, then there is 1/4 of chances that k+1 is white.
When element k is white, then there is 3/4 of chances that k+1 is black.
(You certainly understand that the context part of those two sentences are useless: unconditionally there is 1/4 of chances that k+1 is white, 3/4 of chances that k+1 is black)

So, since there is 3/4 of chances that k is black, that is 3/4×1/4 chances that k is black and k+1 white
and 1/4×3/4 chances that k is white, k+1 black

You already got this, that is in your answer. Just stating plainly the reasoning.

But, that is true only for element 0 and 1. (k=0)

For other k, chance that we are in the first case (k is black and k+1 is white) is biased depending on whether there was a change in previous k.

Just uses Bayes to reverse the thing. Or even plain enumeration:
You had 3/4×1/4 chances that element 0 is black and element 1 is white = 3/16
1/4×3/4 chances that element 0 is white and element 1 is black = 3/16
1/4×1/4 chances that element 0 is white and element 1 is white = 1/16
3/4×3/4 chances that element 0 is black and element 1 is black = 9/16

So, if there was a change between 0 and 1, then you have a 50-50 chances (not a 75-25 as in first element, and as you assume that it is always the case in your reasoning) that element 1 is white.
If there was no change between 0 and 1, then you have 10% chances that it (element 1) is white, and 90% chances that it  is black.

So, if there was a change between element 0 and 1, then the probability to have a change between 1 and 2 becomes 1/2×3/4 + 1/2×1/4 = 1/2 chance (1/2 chance that element 1 is white, and 3/4 that element 2 is black, plus 1/2 chance that element 1 is black and 1/4 chance that element 2 is white).

If there was, on the contrary no change between element 0 and 1, then probability of a change between 1 and 2 is 1/10×3/4 + 9/10×1/4 = 12/40 = 3/10.

So, you don't have 24 independents events here.

Comment: We don't need independencies for expected values of the sum unless I'm wrong? Expectation are always linear, dependent or not.

https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/

Comment: @Leen Not sure I understand the comment. We do need independency (and we haven't it) to be able to just 24×probs to compute expected value. Anyway, you saw yourself that 10 isn't the correct answer.

Comment: @Leen (note that my simulation says 16, not 13. That is because your simulation assumes a 50/50 chances to be black and white, when your statement said 75/25)

Comment: I forgot to add the probabilities in there. Can't believe i forgot that. After adding the 1/4 and 3/4 probabilities in python i get the correct answer of 10. @chrslg, it sounds counterintuitive but you DO NOT need independency to apply linearity of expectation. I struggled with that before too.

```from random import randint
RUNS = 10000

sums = 0
for j in range(RUNS):
    x = []
    for i in range(25):
        x.append(randint(0,3))
    s = 1
    for i in range(1,25):
        if x[i]*x[i-1] == 0 and x[i-1:i+1] != [0,0]:
            s += 1
    sums += s

print(sums/RUNS)
```

Comment: @Leen: yes indeed, of course, you're right. I got confused with "AND" case. But, yes, in this case, it is just adding.

Comment: And then I got too focused on proving that there was no independency to realise that we don't care. So, yes, answer is 10. And problem was simply that you forgot probability. And problem in my own simulation was that I counted the components wrong (I counted the number of times 2 consecutive elements were equal, not different)